# Difficulty constructing Absolute URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, parsing, url

`www.baxter.com` source page, shows most of the href links starting with the word `baxter`, like this -

```
href="/baxter/corporate.page?">About Baxter<
```

So the way I can construct an absolute url from the above is by combining the base url, `www.baxter.com` and the relative url `/baxter/corporate.page?`giving me `www.baxter.com/baxter/corporate.page?` which results in 404, cause the actual url is `www.baxter.com/corporate.page?` 
I know how to generally parse relative URLs in PHP but is there a way to sense and remove words from relative urls like these?

Also mouseover on `About Baxter` on `www.baxter.com` web page displays the correct url, `www.baxter.com/corporate.page?` at bottom left of the page - where is this coming from?  can it be accessed?

Will deeply appreciate any help/pointers...

EDIT on Nov 7:

In main.js, they are removing `/baxter`:

```
var fixer = function() {
var init = function() {
    var digitasFinder = /(proto)|(cms-)|(teamsite-)/
      , baxterFinder = /(\/baxter\/)/
      , $allAnchors = $("a")
      , $allForms = $("form");
    digitasFinder.test(location.host) || ($allAnchors.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this)
          , actualHref = $this.attr("href");
        if (baxterFinder.test(actualHref)) {
            var newHref = actualHref.replace(baxterFinder, "/");
            $this.attr("href", newHref)
        }
    }
    ),
    $allForms.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this)
          , actualAction = $this.attr("action");
        if (baxterFinder.test(actualAction)) {
            var newAction = actualAction.replace(baxterFinder, "/");
            $this.attr("action", newAction)
        }
    }
    ))
}
;
return {
    init: init
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some JavaScript executed on page load is modifying the `href`s of the links.

You could try duplicating the effects of the JS code (ie. remove `'/baxter'` from the links), or for a more generic solution, you could use a headless browser to execute the JS code and then evaluate the resulting DOM. Look into [the Mink project](http://mink.behat.org/) for a PHP-based solution.

Comment: +1 ur right. included the .js code as an edit to my OP, where they remove `/baxter`.  is there a way to capture the generated or final url as showing in Inspect Element of browser??

Comment: to simplify my question - is there a way to capture the modified `href`s?